# how to authenticate users among similar applications using php

Tags: php, session, authentication

Hi have two applications in which database is different for each user.
I have implemented login functionality using sesions but in both the applications code like this

**App 1:**

`

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header('Location:http://localhost/myapp1/login.php');
    exit();
}
```

`

**App 2:**

`

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header('Location:http://localhost/myapp2/login.php');
    exit();
}
```

`

The problem with above approach is even when the user logs into myapp1 he is able to access the myapp2 if the user id exists in both apps.
Please let em know how to solve this.

Comment: A login system that doesn't rely on an easily spoof-able session value would be a fantastic start. I would suggest some basic reading on secure authentication in PHP first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple design problem in your authentication routines. Rather than considering only the `user`, pair it up with the `app` (may be a unique ID you can generate yourself or a name of the app) and maintain those two things in your `session`, to say the least.

Then you could generate access token which should be unique globally. So, even thought you could have the same user on both apps, an access token would not have been generated on the second one.

Also, another flaw I see is that when these are two apps under one umbrella organization, why do you need to maintain multiple tables for different users. Just maintain one user table where the `PRIMARY KEY` is a pair of `(user, app)`.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for this type of answer. Is maintaining two session variables like that a problem or a good practice as session variables are increasing? Also as the apps are not completely same I have to maintain two databases.

Comment: Well, it is OK to have a couple of session variables but not MANY!

Comment: You can accept the answer for others to know!

Comment: How can I restrict users typing my code URLs? I have a models folder in which I am writing my code. If a user types 'localhost/myapp/models/myfilename.php' I want to show him some error page.. How can I do that?

Comment: You need a precondition check there. Just verify that the session variables are set and whether that user is authorized to that access page. Otherwise just redirect to your `error.php`.

Comment: Even after logged in, the user should not access these by typing the URL in the browser.. but should be able to access only through my AJAX calls..

Comment: Its actually OK even if the user can access those URLs because that user won't have some hidden access tokens available even though s/he might know certain parameters that are sent along.